# Why is Spark explode function much slower than a flat map function to split array?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm new to Spark and Spark SQL. I have a dataset of 2 columns, "col1" and "col2", and "col2" originally is a Seq of longs. I want to explode "col2" into multiple rows so that each row only has one long.

I tried the explode function versus using `flatMap` and my own mapper function. They seemed to have significant performance difference. Everything else remained the same, "explode" function seems to be much slower than `flatMap` (order of magnitude depends on data size). Why?

**Option 1: Using "explode"**

```scala
val exploded = data.withColumn("col2", explode(col("col2")))
```

**Option 2: Using manual flatMap**

```scala
case class MyPair(col1: Long, col2: Long)

def longAndLongArrayMapper(colToKeep: Long, colToExplode: Seq[Long]) = {
    (for (val <- colToExplode) yield MyPair(val, colToKeep))
 }

val exploded = data.flatMap{ (x: Row) =>
      longAndLongArrayMapper(x.getAs[Long]("col1"), (x.getAs[Seq[Long]]("col2"))) }
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657